# Overwriting field on on entity with a default value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an entity with a field with a value(that can be null). In another table I have the default value. I want to override the entity's value(with the one from the defaults table) if it's null.

```
products
+- country_id -+- price -+
|           1  |   100   |
|           2  |   NULL  |
+--------------+---------+

defaults
+- country_id -+- price -+
|           1 |      10  |
|           2 |      99  |
+-------------+----------+

// this product should load price from defaults
$product = $productRepository->findOneBy(['country_id' => 2]);
```

Is there something is Symfony that will allow me this?

Maybe though constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints are not an option. May be you can achieve it by `postLoad` event which is provided by Doctrine, ([documentation is here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html)), like this:

```
public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof YOUR_ENTITY)
    {
        if (null == $entity->getMYFIELD())
        {
            $entity->setMYFIELD(NEW_VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't try it, I haven't tried this at all, but I think it should help you to get an idea..

Answer (score 1):

You could define a one to one relation between Products and Defaults and then have this getter:

```
function getPrice()
{
    if (null === $this->price) 
    {
        return $this->default->getPrice();
    }

    return $this->price; 
}
```

PD: I can't comment on xurshid29's post, but that probably won't work as he needs to retrieve the value from a table, and injecting any repository will throw a circular reference exception (he could inject the container though).

Answer (score 0):

To override value upon retrieval, extends Doctrine `EntityRepository` so you can override and/or create [custom method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes). For example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneByCountry($country_id)
    {
        $product = $this->findOneBy(['country_id' => $country_id]);
        if ($product->getPrice() === null) {
            $default = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Default')
                ->findOneBy(['country_id' => $country_id])
            ;

            $product->setPrice($default->getPrice());
        }
    }
}
```